# What is the purpose of this Y shaped bit?

Tags: tools

I have bought a bits set and there is this bit:
[image: a bit with a groove]

It is a Y shaped bit, and there is a groove on the inside of the branches. The angle is approximatively 90˚ (a little more).

Comment: Re. your edit: "shaped" is actually the correct word to use here, not "shape"

Comment: @NiallC. OK I canceled my edit. As a non-native speaker I trusted the wording on Tester101's answer - which happens to be wrong..

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's a bit for screwing in [eye bolts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_bolt), or hooks.

[image: eyebolt]
[image: open loop or hook screw]

- Attach the bit to your driver handle or power driver.
- Fit the eye bolt into the groove.
- Screw the bolt in/out, without hurting your fingers.

The list of bits in this [set](http://www.harborfreight.com/100-piece-security-bit-set-68457.html), lists it as a "Y-shape hook driver".

> [image: 100 piece "security" bit set and plastic case]
> [image: screenshot of available bits highlighting Y-shaped driver]

Comment: I tried it this morning, and it works perfectly. But on some eye bolts, there is thin layer of white plastic (I don't know the exact nature or term for it) that get damaged in the process.

Comment: I always predrill the hole, and then driving it by hand is easy.

Comment: If the screw-in action is too difficult, try rubbing the thread along a bar of soap first. Works with screws, too.

Comment: We use these on the farm to anchor eye bolts in stalls and isles, we have several sizes, I still pre drill so I don't split the posts but makes it easy to install eye bolts for cross ties, prior to finding these many years ago I used j hooks on a drill and if no power tools a long screwdriver , or a heavy 16" nail that we use to anchor rubber belting to the ground.

Answer (score 5):

Also can be used for wing nuts.

Comment: Seems to me that if a wing nut needs a tool it probably shouldn't be a wing nut.